# Positivity of a polynomial with a fractional order term

Tags: inequality, fractional-calculus

I'm trying to show this problem.

> Show that
>   $$
> f(x):=2(2-a)(3-a)x^{2}-5(3-a)x+6-9(1-x)^{3-a}
> $$
>   is positive on $\{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid \frac{2}{3}<x\le1\}$ for all $a\in(0,1)$.

I have tried to remove the fractional order of the last term but I could not show well. More precisely, I estimated as follows:
$$
f(x)>2(2-a)(3-a)x^{2}-5(3-a)x+6-9(1-x)^{2},
$$
but the right-hand side becomes negative near $x=\frac{2}{3}$ for $a\approx0.6〜0.7$.
Although I consider the above problem since I want to show an inequality
$$
2(2-a)(3-a)x^{2}-5(3-a)x+6>9(1-x)^{3-a}\quad\text{on $\{x \mid 2/3<x\le1\}$},
$$
please tell me if you have another approach.

I'm glad if you give a hint or solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If we change the variable $y=1/x$, then the desired inequality becomes $(y-1)^{3-a}<?-5 (y^{3-a})'+2(y^{3-a})''$. Not sure if this helps, though.

Comment: why this postive? this problem is from some book or ?

Comment: You could replace the R.H.S. of the inequality $(1-x)^{3-a} \leq (1-x)^2$ with $(1-x)^2\left(1-(1-a)x\right)$.

Comment: @math110 It's from books but I forgot its book's name...

Comment: @Aravind I did'n think of its replacing. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

hint:
let
$$G(x)=2(2-a)(3-a)x^2-5(3-a)x+6-9(1-x)^{3-a}$$
then
$$G'(x)=4(2-a)(3-a)x-5(3-a)+9(3-a)(1-x)^{2-a}=(3-a)H(x)$$
where
$$H(x)=4(2-a)x-5+9(1-x)^{2-a}$$
then
$$H'(x)=4(2-a)-9(2-a)(1-x)^{1-a}=(2-a)Q(x)$$
where
$$Q(x)=4-9(1-x)^{1-a}$$
you can determine the $Q(x)$ sign?

Comment: @math100 Thank you for giving comment. I have tried its approach but $Q(x)$ changes sign by depending on $a$. However, I flashed good idea.